# Error handling in Cloud functions - Cloud Logging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I have a series of cloud functions and I want to get an alert when errors occur in them. I already have the alert set and it works.
I decided to use the Cloud Logging logs: functions.logger.error(Error ${error.message});
But for example when my function times out and I go to Logs Explorer I see these logs:
"Function execution started" followed by
"Function execution took 4999 ms, finished with status: '**error**' " or "Function execution took 4999 ms, finished with status: '**timeout**' "

What should I do to handle those **errors** correctly? I tried to catch them but without good results. I would like to get a log with an ERROR severity (now their severity is DEBUG) in Cloud logging and therefore, get an alert sent to my email.
An example of a cloud function that results in timeout is:
`exports.function = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 5 }).https.onCall(async (data, context) => { try{ await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000)); }catch(error){ functions.logger.error(`Error ${error.message}`); return { status: 400, message: "Error in function" }; } });`
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can modify your function by using a try-catch block and the `functions.logger.error()` method. In the catch block, you can log the error message with the appropriate severity level.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Kozydot. I have tried that but with no success. I tried what 's in the post above adding the severity inside the catch like this:
catch(error){
    console.log("--error-->", error)
   functions.logger.error(`Error ${error.message}`, {
    error: error.message,
    requestBody: context.rawRequest.body.data,
    severity: 'ERROR',
  });
  return { status: 400, message: "Error in function" };
}

Comment: But it still doesn't log the error in cloud logging. Can you tell me how you did it if it worked for you? @Kozydot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch a TIMEOUT error in your code because that error happens outside of your code.  Your code is not notified that the Cloud Function engine is terminating its execution.

Likely the best move is to [create an Alert in your GCP Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts#lba-definition) to be notified of a timeout log entry.